# How to change main window view from a pop up window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to learn MVVM but am finding it a nightmare trying to understand how to correctly navigate between views in an application using MVVM. After some time researching and trying to understand different techniques I have come across an approach from [Rachel Lim's blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/). This technique uses a ViewModel for the application itself and keeps track of the application state such as the current page. I feel this would be a nice approach to follow for my application.

Now moving onto my problem..

**What I want to achieve**

I want an application that has a one main application view that will store a LoginView and a HomeView as DataTemplates and have a content control that sets the LoginView as the view displayed when the application is started. The LoginView will have a button that when pressed will open another window that has a button. When the button in the pop up window is pressed I want to change the view in the main application window from LoginView to the HomeView.

**What I have so far**

I have a set up the ApplicationView which works fine.

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Navigation_Practice.Views.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPF_Navigation_Practice.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WPF_Navigation_Practice.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ApplicationViewModel}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
            <views:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
            <views:HomeView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And have set up the ApplicationViewModel as follows. Setting the current page to the LoginViewModel.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using WPF_Navigation_Practice.Interfaces;

namespace WPF_Navigation_Practice.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that a View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;

        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        #endregion

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
            // Add available pages
            PageViewModels.Add(new LoginViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new HomeViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new CodeViewModel());


            // Set starting page
            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        #region Properties / Commands

        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IPageViewModel);
                }

                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
                {
                    _currentPageViewModel = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
                }
            }
        }


        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

When I run the application it will display my main Application window which displays the loginView which is a UserControl and is set as the currentPageViewModel with ContentPresenter.

When the button in the LoginView UserControl is clicked it will open another window. As per the image below.

[image]

Here is the XAML for that window.

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Navigation_Practice.Views.CodeView"
    x:Name="CodeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPF_Navigation_Practice.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    d:DesignWidth="623.224" d:DesignHeight="381.269"
    DataContext="{Binding CodeViewModel, Source={StaticResource ApplicationViewModel}}">

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Ok" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="235,166,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="138" 
            FontSize="20" 
            Height="67"/>
    <Label Content="Second Window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

**My Problem**

What I want to achieve is when the 'Ok' button in the secondView window is clicked, I want to change the currentPageViewModel in the ApplicationView Window from the LoginView to display the HomeView but am confused on how I would go about achieving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I might give the loginview a LoggedIn event that the main view subscribes to. Then when that's raised, the main view can tell the application viewmodel that somebody logged in, by setting a property on it (it == app vm), calling a method, whatever. There should be One Viewmodel to Rule Them all, who makes decision about stuff like what to do when the user logs in -- I'm assuming that's the application viewmodel.

Comment: MVVM is honestly not well designed for having multiple windows (including dialogs etc). If possible, use a single window, and plug in different UserControls (each considered a View).

Comment: Any issues with passing main-window as parameter to the constructor of popup window, and setting view from there using main-window's property.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are already using MVVMLight. There is a Messenger class which can help you here. Register to the messenger in your ApplicationViewModel Constructor and in the code handling the button click in CodeViewModel use Send to send a message. In the action you pass on to register change the viewmodels as you wish.

See http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/9fb9c53a-943a-11d7-9517-c550440c3664.htm
and [Use MVVM Light's Messenger to Pass Values Between View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087906/use-mvvm-lights-messenger-to-pass-values-between-view-model)

I don't have MVVMLight to write you a sample code. I've written a ViewModelMessenger from scratch and mine is like this:

```
public static void Register(string actionName, object registerer, Action<object, object> action)
{
    var actionKey = new Tuple<string, object>(actionName, registerer);
    if (!RegisteredActions.ContainsKey(actionKey))
    {
        RegisteredActions.Add(actionKey, action);
    }
    else
    {
        RegisteredActions[actionKey] = action;
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
VMMessenger.Register("ChangeViewModel",this,ChangeViewModelAction)
```

and

```
public static void SendMessage(string messageName, object message, object sender)
{
    var actionKeys = RegisteredActions.Keys.ToList();
    foreach (Tuple<string, object> actionKey in actionKeys)
    {
        if (actionKey.Item1 == messageName)
        {
            Action<object, object> action;
            if (RegisteredActions.TryGetValue(actionKey, out action))
            {
                action?.Invoke(message, sender);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
VMMessenger.SendMessage("ChangeViewModel","HomeViewModel",this);
```

and in `ChangeViewModelAction` you can check for ViewModel names and change the CurrentPageViewModel to one with a matching name.